# Odd Characters Being Added in IE8

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2008-r2

When I view a page in anything apart from IE8, it shows properly. When I view the source code (in IE8 only) it looks fine as below

[image: working]

However when I copy/paste it into http://jsbeautifier.org/ or notepad, it looks odd. In notepad, the first line is distorted and on JS Beautifier, there are 2 red circles.

[image: broken]
[image: broken]

I'm using WordPress on Windows Server 2008 R2. As I said, the page works in everything apart from IE8. Any ideas?

Also adds something to the end

[image: broken]

Comment: I would guess those two bytes are the UTF-8 BOM header. You can ignore that.

Comment: ... it seems to break the page though. Removing the start and end and saving it as a HTML file seems to work fine

Comment: Try to open that file in a hex editor and copy the first and last three hex values.

Comment: ï»¿ï»¿ï»¿ in the header and ... in the footer

Comment: Okay I checked it the BOM header consists out of 3 bytes not two as in my mind so I was correct.

Comment: I removed them but it keeps coming back.Opened in notepad and saved as UTF-8. Using WordPress - could that be an issue?

Comment: That is the issue you must not save it as UTF-8 with notepad. it adds the header. Use some other editor.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the [UTF-BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding) header. There you can also see that the three bytes from the comment is equal the utf-8 byte order mark header. Just remove them and everything should still work fine.

Just the bytes at the end are confusing me. They are if you quoted them correctly also a BOM header but this is wrong. Just remove those one too and you should be done.